# How to convert JS code to Kotlin without the 'new' keyword

Tags: javascript, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm looking into converting some basic JS to Kotlin but I'm stuck on the `new` keyword. I'm not sure how to convert the following JS to Kotlin

```
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
var fcm = new FCM('YOURSERVERKEYHERE');
var message = { ... };
fcm.send(message, function(err, response){ ... }
```

I tried

```
fun sendTestPush() {
  val FCM = require("fcm-push")
  val fcm = new FCM("YOURSERVERKEYHERE")

  val data = Data("Title", "Message")
  val message = Message("registration_id", data)

  fcm.send(message)
}

data class Message(val to: String, val data: Data)
data class Data(val title: String, val message: String)
```

I get the compile error `Unresolved reference: new` as Kotlin doesn't have it.
Without the 'new' I get the expected error `Attempting to TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Any idea to get around this problem?

Edit: FCM class is the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push

Comment: What's the FCM class?

Comment: you'll have to use `js()` to wrap your JavaScript library.  see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/calling-javascript-from-kotlin/calling-javascript-from-kotlin.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but your answer you marked as correct, is in fact incorrect. I have to say this, since someone who is looking for the right answer might find it and write incorrect code. Generally, you shouldn't call the `require` function from Kotlin directly. Rather, you should use [`@JsModule`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-module/index.html) together with `external` declarations. In your particular case it would be something like this:

```
@JsModule("fcm-push")
external class FCM(serverKey: String) {
   fun send(message: Any?, callback: (err: Any?, response: Any?) -> Unit)
   fun send(message: Any?): Promise<Any>
}

val serverKey = "YOURSERVERKEYHERE"
val fcm = FCM(serverKey)
//...
fcm.send(message)
```

Also, you should pass `commonjs` to the `moduleKind` compiler flag. See the [corresponding documentation page](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html) for a full description.

Comment: Legend, thanks for this. I did have to make it ```external class FCM(key: String) {``` to accept the serverKey in. marked as accepted. I'm not yet sure how to go about the callback or Promise part of your code, but maybe that should be a another question

Answer (score 1):

The [require function in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) is not the same as the [require in NodeJS](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8) which is probably used in your JS code.

Whatever your FCM class is, just instantiate it without the `new` keyword.

Comment: Sorry added an edit, its the fcm-push npm module from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push . It only works in NodeJS with the `new` and can't figure out how to get it going in kotlin

Comment: @JaredHall I think i misunderstood the question, you still want your code to compile to JS, not 'transfer' it to Kotlin on the JVM, right?

Comment: Correct. I thought the best way for me to learn was to start converting some smaller classes to kotlin first within my larger nodejs project

Answer (score 1):

<s>Thanks to a hint from @Claies I managed get it to work using the `js(...)` wrap.~~~</s>

```
val FCM = require("fcm-push")
val serverKey = "YOURSERVERKEYHERE"
val fcm = js("new FCM(serverKey)")
...
fcm.send(message) // now works
```

I'm not sure I'm totally happy with the writing pure js inside a string in kotlin so I hope there is a better way that I've missed.

Edit: The above works, but its not ideal, refer to accepted answer for better implementation